# Nuxt store mutation recieving TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuex

I set up a simple store in store/index.js that looks like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
    isDark: false,
});

export const mutations = {
    setIsDark(state, payload) {
        state.isDark = payload;
    },
};

export const getters = {
    getIsDark(state) {
        return state.isDark;
    },
};
```

I'm able to get isDark in my component but when I try to call setIsDark I get a error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIsDark' of undefined
```

My component:

```
computed: {
    isDark() {
        return this.$store.getters.getIsDark;
    },
},

methods: {
    toggleIsDark() {
        this.$store.mutations.setIsDark(!this.isDark);
    },
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for calling a mutation is:

```js
this.$store.commit('setIsDark', !this.isDark);
```

For an action, it's:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('setIsDark', !this.isDark);
```